# Combine explicit protocol specification with relative URL

Tags: javascript, https

I have a page that is accessed via HTTP. This page links to another page on the same server using HTTPS.  What is the most elegant way, using HTML and/or Javascript, to force a transition to HTTPS while using a relative URL?

Basically, I want the opposite of a [protocol-relative URL](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/). I want to explicitly specify HTTPS WITHOUT hardcoding the hostname into the URL.

I'm working on a large legacy site so a solution using unobtrusive javascript with minimal changes to existing markup is ideal.

I realize that enforcing HTTPS is better performed at the *destination* page, but that isn't an option in this case.

Comment: It's a `<a href="...">` element you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").each(function () { 
    this.href = "https://" + window.location.host + this.pathname + this.search + this.hash;
});
```

You could provide a more specific selector to make sure it doesn't mess up any links you didn't intend to change, but I leave that up to you since you know the requirements.

Comment: Don't forget to add the slash to the concatenation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to build the URL yourself from the pieces on `window.location`.

```
var path = anchor.href;

var httpsUrl = "https://" + 
  window.location.host + 
  (path.charAt(0) === '/' ? path : window.location.pathname + '/' + path);
```

or something like that (esp. if there's are parameters etc).

*edit* — it's been noted that modern browsers will give back the complete URL when you access the "href" value, making this an even easier problem to solve in those cases (as you just have to fix the protocol prefix). (Thanks @Daniel!)

Comment: Yeah, I've pretty much accepted that. I was just hoping someone could point out a library or jquery plugin or something that turned that into a one-liner. It's not hard to build, but if someone's already been through all the edge cases and identified a clean, unobtrusive way of wiring it up.....

Comment: I don't think this would work. `anchor.href` is resolved to the full URL even if the provided href was a relative URL.

Comment: @Daniel that's true in modern browsers, making this even easier to do, but not true in old versions of IE. Before IE8, you'd get back whatever was authored into the attribute in the original markup.

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks! Good to know. I don't have any old browsers installed (ignorance is bliss as they say). Do you know if the `anchor.pathname` property is automatically resolved in older browsers for relative URLs? I would assume so -- if so, you can let the browser do some of the work and remove that conditional logic for the relative URLs.

Comment: @Daniel I don't remember exactly - that kind of thing is not something I've really had to deal with very much, so most of what I know is from stuff I've read here and there, and a small amount of random experience.

Comment: FWIW `.href` returns the fully qualified url consistently, even in old IEs. You're thinking of `.getAttribute('href')` which by spec should return the value set in source, but IE forces you to pass in a magic second argument to it in order to get the raw attribute value.